# I can't see a point in which to connect my nodes (Solved, wrong node)

Tags: materials, node-editor

So I don't know if I'm being an idiot or what, but I can't seem to link my value nodes together in the same way as the tutorial.

I'm assuming I don't have the correct node?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My Nodes:

[image]

Tutorial Nodes:

[image]

Comment: Which tutorial? Please provide at least an image or even better more information about what you'd like to do.

Comment: Sorry, realised my mistake and added them now. Cheers!

Comment: Cool, thanks. Yeah, it's the wrong node type so just put down a math node instead of a value node.

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman. Thanks a bunch, really helped me out :)

Comment: Hi. Please don't add 'solved' to the title. Either ask @brockmann to write an answer or write an answer yourself, then 'accept' it as correct. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Cool, thanks. Yeah, it's the wrong node type so just put down a math node instead of a value node. – brockmann Jan 24 at 11:49 "